# Creating instance names from a list (Python)

Tags: python

I've got a function that builds a random number of object instances. For the sake of demonstrating the general idea, we're going to pretend that this is an algorithm to build a series of nethack-like rooms.

The requirements are such that I won't know how many instances there will be in advance; these are generated randomly and on-the-fly.

As a brief note: I am fully aware that the following code is nonfunctional, but it should (hopefully!) demonstrate my aims.

```
import random

class Levelbuild(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.l1 = dict({0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:'e',5:'f',6:'g',7:'h',8:'i'})
        # Pick a random number between 4 and 9.
        for i in range(random.randint(4,9)):
            self.l1[i] = Roombuilder()
```

If we assume that the chosen random integer is 5, the ideal result would be 5 Roombuilder() instances; labeled a, b, c, d, and e, respectively.

Is there a simple way of doing this? Is there a way to do this period?

--Edit--

A giant "thank you" to Nick ODell for his answer. This isn't a complete copy/paste-- but it's a variation that works for what I need;

```
import random

class Room(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = (5,5)

class Level(object):

    def __init__(self):
        roomnames = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
        self.rooms = {}
        for i in range(random.randint(4, 9)):
            self.rooms[roomnames[i]] = Room()
```

Rather than build each "room" by hand, I can now...

```
test = Level()
print test.rooms['a'].size
>>> (5,5)
```

Comment: What is the issue here? Generating the letters to go with the numbers? Assigning the labels to the class? I'm not really sure what you are having an issue with here.

Comment: So you want n level objects as named members of the Levelbuild class?  You might want to reconsider your design, as you probably want them stored as a more easily iterable ordered data set, like a list or ordered dict, and stored under a levelmanager or levelstore rather than under the builder itself.

Comment: For what it's worth, the easiest way to generate the names would be do to ``dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))`` - presuming you knew you'd always have under 26 items. (Which presumably is all right given your current solution).

Comment: @Lattyware: the issue is largely in generating unique labels to be assigned to each instance of the Roombuilder class (as noted below: poor name for a class, and has been duly adjusted to simply 'Room'). In any given "level," there can be fluctuating numbers of rooms that I need to refer to, with labels that I can't/won't know at the time of coding. I'd thought that this method would allow me to quickly fetch the individual rooms attributes with something like `Levelbuild.l1.keys()`, for example.

Comment: @sr2222: ideally, I'll be able to call the "level builder" to initialize all the needed rooms; and then use the `dict` attribute as a means of indexing and calling those respective rooms.

Comment: Is there a reason they need names as a string? Why not just keep them as a list and hold references to individual items as needed? Otherwise, see my answer for a general solution for generating names automatically.

Comment: @KayDee I'm not sure you have object oriented design down, quite.  I think what you are looking for is a `Level` object that has a `populate()` or `generate_rooms()` method on it.  Levelbuild seems to be adding complexity without value for you right now.

Comment: @sr2222: The posted syntax was designed to make it as "basic" as possible; the lines I put up in the first place would be considered the 'generate_rooms()' method in the `Level` object. In debugging, I have that code under `__init__()` as a way of simplifying the testing portion, so I can just create the `Level` class and see if whatever change I made does what I want it to. In some sense, I'm trying to form a container that holds the objects I need to refer to; while on `desert.Level()`, I can easily access individual desert rooms, along with "desert globals" (for lack of a better term)

Comment: @Lattyware: No _good_ reason. I'm still sort of fumbling along while teaching myself; I'll try to adjust what I've got accordingly, and get into a better habit.

Comment: I'd modify `range(random.randint(4, 9))` to `range(random.randint(4, len(roomnames)))` so that you don't have 2 independent points in the code controlling your max number of rooms.  You could even do `for i in roomnames[:random.randint(4, 9)]: self.rooms[i] = Room()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
import random

class Levelbuild(object):

  def __init__(self,min_room_count,max_room_count):

    rooms_temp = [new RoomBuilder() for i in range(random.randint(min_room_count,max_room_count))]
    self.l1 = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, rooms_temp))
```

Note: This will fail silently if given more than 26 rooms.

Comment: A clean and simple Pythonic approach.

Comment: This isn't quite exactly what I'm using-- but it gave me the info I needed, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, actually.  You don't need a dict; just use a list.  (And, by the way, `{...}` is already a dict, so wrapping it in `dict()` doesn't do anything.)

```
roomnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
self.rooms = []
for i in range(random.randint(4, 9)):
    self.rooms.append(Roombuilder(roomnames[i]))
```

For what it's worth, putting `builder` in the name of a class is kind of funky.  The objects are rooms, right?  So the type should just be `Room`.

Comment: It's perfectly appropriate to put builder in the class name depending upon implementation.  However, it does not really make sense to store the built items as members of the class if you call it a builder.

Comment: @sr2222: Sure, sometimes you actually have an object that just makes other objects.  That doesn't look to be the case here, though.  If it is, disregard  :)

Comment: Better `for nameint, i in enumerate(...): self.rooms.append(Roombuilder(chr(ord('a') + nameint)))` or similar so you don't a list of names.

Comment: @agf I'm hoping he doesn't always intend to use ascending letters for the room names, in which case ascii tricks are more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: @sr2222: The nomenclature was incorrect on my part, and largely a result of a rush-job in trying to cut all my code down to demonstrate the source of the problem.

Comment: @Eevee: What's the danger of just using letters for the room names? I can just as easily use other words-- but in the context of the full code, I'll be primarily using dict.keys() as a way of checking info on all the rooms at once; save for special cases (differentiating between a "special" room versus a randomly generated one), I won't be often referring to the individual rooms by name. In the case of the "special" room, I can call the Room class by hand.

Comment: @KayDee Have you considered that you might want your rooms in an ordered data structure?  I understand that this is a random level generator, but within one instance of a level, it'd probably be best if the relative positions of rooms was guaranteed deterministic.

Comment: @sr2222 I could be misunderstanding you-- but I believe that's what I've got in my current iteration. The random generation occurs once per level, at which point the rooms' respective locations are saved to that particular level object; should a player leave a level and re-enter it, that level will remain the same. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: You are creating a dictionary to contain your rooms.  A dictionary is unordered data (if you iterate over the elements, you are not guaranteed to get them in the same order each time and you can't index them by position).  If you built them as members of a namedtuple, a list, or an ordereddict, they'd have an order inherently.  Maybe it wouldn't help you, but I could see it being a good thing to have guaranteed order of your rooms within a level.

Comment: @KayDee: If you're not referring to the rooms by name, why do they need names at all?  Forget about the letters and just make a list of them (or set, or whatever).

Comment: @sr2222 / @Eevee : my naming of the rooms was purely a matter of comfort, and not necessarily the most efficient or useful way of doing this. I'll take a look at how I'm planning on having everything mesh together-- and if the `dict()` isn't needed, set them up as a list/set/whathaveyou. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

As another answer for a more general solution (mainly as a companion to [Nick ODell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323136/722121), if you want to handle any number of names, it's a pretty simply solution with an infinite generator:

```
import string
import itertools

def generate_names(characters):
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        for name in itertools.product(characters, repeat=i):
            yield "".join(name)
```

You can then use it as you would any other generator:

```
>>>print(dict(zip(generate_names(string.ascii_lowercase), range(30))))
{'aa': 26, 'ac': 28, 'ab': 27, 'ad': 29, 'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5, 'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14, 'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20, 't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
```

If you need to generate actual *names*, then you have a few choices. If you need a real word, pick from a dictionary file (most Linux users have one in `/usr/share/dict`). If you need word-like things, then I have actually written [a Python script to generate such 'words' using Markov Chains](http://www.lattyware.co.uk/projects/wordgenerator), which is available under the GPL. Naturally, you'd have to check these for uniqueness.